# get child folders ID

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a folder and some child folders, I want to get the names and the ids of every child folders :

```
const ROOT_FOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
const FOLDERS = ROOT_FOLDER.getFolders();
const FOLDERS_NAMES = [ROOT_FOLDER.getName()]; 

//get child folders names
while (FOLDERS.hasNext()) {
  var folder = FOLDERS.next();
  var folderName = folder.getName(); 
  FOLDERS_NAMES.push(folderName);
}
  
//get child folders IDs
const FOLDERS_IDS =  [];

while (FOLDERS.hasNext()) {
  var folder = FOLDERS.next();
  var folderID = folder.getId(); 
  FOLDERS_IDS.push(folderID);
}
```

The while loop for the names works fine, the IDs loop raise an undefined error on the folder.getId(), I don't understand why.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it worked with this :

```
const ROOT_FOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const FOLDERS = ROOT_FOLDER.getFolders();
  const FOLDERS_NAMES = [ROOT_FOLDER.getName()]; 
  const FOLDERS_IDS =  [];

  while (FOLDERS.hasNext()) {
    var folder = FOLDERS.next();
    var folderName = folder.getName();
    FOLDERS_NAMES.push(folderName);
    var folderID = folder.getId(); 
    FOLDERS_IDS.push(folderID);
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).